# Vue Router this.$route.router undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to redirect the url using `router.push({ path: 'customers', query : mergedQuery });` but I can't get a correct reference to `router` property.

I feel like I'm missing something in the app.js but not sure which one. Inside component `this.$route` has some stuff inside it but there's no `router` property.

app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.VueRouter = require('vue-router');
window.VueResource = require('vue-resource'); 
window.Vue.use(window.VueRouter);

const routes = [
        { path: '/', component: require('./components/dashboard.vue')  },
        { path: '/customers/', component: require('./components/customers/list.vue')  },
    ];
const router = new VueRouter({routes});
const app = new Vue({router}).$mount('#app');
```

.vue file

```
console.log(this.$route.router); //undefined
```

Comment: Isn't `this.$router.push` working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing it incorrectly. According to the [official docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/component-injections.html), router is available inside component instances as `this.$router`.